# XML Dom Parsing to List in Apex

Tags: xml, dom, salesforce, apex

From the below `XML` need to get values based on the respective keys and add convert it to `List<User>` using **apex code**

```
<users>
 <user>
  <prop key="FirstName" value="Ramesh"/>
  <prop key="lastName" value="Ramesh"/>
  <prop key="DOB" value="29/03/1988"/>
  <prop key="Mobile" value="12345678"/>
  <prop key="Country" value="India"/>
</user>
<user>
  <prop key="FirstName" value="Anil"/>
  <prop key="lastName" value="Ramesh"/>
  <prop key="DOB" value="29/03/1986"/>
  <prop key="Mobile" value="12345678"/>
  <prop key="Country" value="India"/>
</user>
</users>
```

Tried using below code but couldn't able to find

```
private String walkThrough(DOM.XMLNode node) {
  String result = '\n';
  if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.COMMENT) {
    return 'Comment (' +  node.getText() + ')';
  }
  if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.TEXT) {
    return 'Text (' + node.getText() + ')';
  }
  if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.ELEMENT) {
    result += 'Element: ' + node.getName();
    if (node.getText().trim() != '') {
      result += ', text=' + node.getText().trim();
    }
    if (node.getAttributeCount() > 0) { 
      for (Integer i = 0; i< node.getAttributeCount(); i++ ) {
        result += ', attribute #' + i + ':' + node.getAttributeKeyAt(i) + '=' + node.getAttributeValue(node.getAttributeKeyAt(i), node.getAttributeKeyNsAt(i));
      }  
    }
    for (Dom.XMLNode child: node.getChildElements()) {
      result += walkThrough(child);
    }
    return result;
  }
  return '';  //should never reach here 
}

private String parse(String toParse) {
  DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();      
  try {
    doc.load(toParse);    
    DOM.XMLNode root = doc.getRootElement();
    return walkThrough(root);

  } catch (System.XMLException e) {  // invalid XML
    return e.getMessage();
  }
}
```

Can some help me how to get value based on the Key using DOM document for the above XML?

Answer (score 0):

I had basically the same issue. My solution looks roughly like this:

```
public with sharing class SG_WF_XML_PARSE_POC {

    public User selectedUser { get; set; }
    public String Field1{get; set;}
    public String Label1{get; set;}
    public String Field2{get; set;}
    public String Label2{get; set;}
    public String Field3{get; set;}
    public String Label3{get; set;}
    public String Field4{get; set;}
    public String Label4{get; set;}
    public String Field5{get; set;}
    public String Label5{get; set;}
    public String sObjectName { get; set; }
    public List<String> FieldList {get; set;}
    private Map<String, String> readxml; 
    private final Request_APAC__c reqs;


    public SG_WF_XML_PARSE_POC(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.reqs = (Request_APAC__c)stdController.getRecord();
        System.debug('Initializing stdcontr: ' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') + ' - ' + reqs);
        Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(reqs.XML_Store__c); 
        Dom.XMLNode env= doc.getRootElement();
        Field1 = env.getAttribute('field', 'Workflow');
        system.debug('root : '+env.getname());
        for (Dom.XmlNode node : doc.getRootElement().getChildElements()) {
            String a1 = node.getname();
            system.debug('getname son attribute='+a1 );
            for (Dom.XmlNode node1 : node.getChildElements()) {
                String a11 = node1.getname();
                String a111 = node1.gettext();
                if (node1.getname() == 'label') {
                    label1 = node1.gettext();
                    label2 = node1.gettext();
                    label3 = node1.gettext();
                    label4 = node1.gettext();
                }
                system.debug('gettext grandson attribute='+a11 + ' value=' + a111);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ... 
}
```